# Threading - no access to methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working with threads for the first time. I have a main class (mainProgram) and a thread class that extends Thread. In the main class I have this:

```
public void runThreads() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new mainProgram().new ThreadOne());
}
```

In the sub class I have this method:

```
public void setActive(){
    if(active){
        active = false;
    } 
}
```

Why isn't it possible to call `t1.setActive()` and how do I solve that?

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to call setActive?

Comment: t1.setActive(). Since you are asking I'm guessing it's wrong?

Comment: you declared t1 as type Thread not "ThreadOne" (which I'm assuming is your extension of the Thread class.

Comment: You need to override run method on Thread.class by calling setActive(); also you need to call t1.start(); to start the new thread.

Comment: Thanks guys. The reason I wrote this (new Thread(new mainProgram().new ThreadOne());) is because I couldn't just create a new instance of ThreadOne in static main. I could in a method though so I figured it out

Comment: You can post your solution and accept it